# Leaflet animation is not working when i zoom in

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I want to implement animation like on this example

```
http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html
```

But by me everything is working,except animation

```
  this.markerClusterGroup = L.markerClusterGroup({ removeOutsideVisibleBounds: true, animate: true,
      animateAddingMarkers: true });
```

I also imported the styles

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.css">
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: When you look into the source code of the page, you see that there are no addintional options for the merkerClusterGroup are set.

Comment: Can you please provide me the link ? I didn't find such a thing :S

Comment: go on the link you posted and then make a right click on the white background and select "View page source" or use the shortcut CTRL+U

Comment: I can't understand how the vie page source can help me.It is library it is not custom css. I need to configure something

Comment: Because when you check the source code of the page, you can easily see how the cluster script is configured.

Comment: Did you add any markers to `this.markerClusterGroup` and add this group to the map?

Comment: Yes i did that.

Comment: No, in the view source code i found the script tag but there is nothing for animation